# Programmatically adding TextView to Grid Layout alignment not proper

Tags: android, dynamic, android-gridlayout

Hi i am trying to add TextView with drawableLeft to GridLayout.
I am adding this TextView in an Loop. The TextView are getting added properly but the are not aligned properly. Each textview should take equal width in one horizontal row which is not happening.

Following is the code i am using

```
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(getContext());
            gridLayout.setAlignmentMode(GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS);
            gridLayout.setColumnCount(2);
            gridLayout.setRowCount(3);
            TextView titleText;
            for (int i = 0; facilities != null && i < facilities.size(); i++) {
                titleText = new TextView(getContext());
                titleText.setText(facilities.get(i));
                gridLayout.addView(titleText, i);
                titleText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(rightIc, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For this you have to dynamically set the column width for the views. This will finally align each view properly with equal amount of space.

```
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(getContext());
            gridLayout.setAlignmentMode(GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS);
            gridLayout.setColumnCount(2);
            gridLayout.setRowCount(3);
            TextView titleText;
            for (int i = 0; facilities != null && i < facilities.size(); i++) {
                titleText = new TextView(getContext());
                titleText.setText(facilities.get(i));
                gridLayout.addView(titleText, i);
                titleText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(rightIc, 0, 0, 0);
                GridLayout.LayoutParams param =new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
                param.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                param.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                param.rightMargin = 5;
                param.topMargin = 5;
                param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(c);
                param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(r);
                titleText.setLayoutParams (param);

}
```

Comment: what is c and r here?

Comment: c is column index and r is row index of GridLayout

Comment: Column and row indices start at 0, if anybody is wondering as well.

Comment: this might be helpful to someone.

to place grid item with equal width and height

                param.columnSpec =
                    GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f)
                param.rowSpec =
                    GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f)

Answer (score 4):

The following code sample should give each text view equal height and width, and order the TextViews left-to-right and then top-to-bottom.

The critical part is explicitly providing the GridLayout.LayoutParams, setting height/width to 0 and defining the row/column specs with weights set to 1 so that the height and width will be automatically calculated based on the weights.

Also notice I set the number of rows as a function of the number of facilities, so that if your list grows you'll have more rows.

```
if (facilities == null) {
    // In this case there is nothing to display. You can adjust this part to your needs.
    return;
}

GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(getContext());
gridLayout.setAlignmentMode(GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS);
gridLayout.setColumnCount(2);
gridLayout.setRowCount(facilities.size() / 2);
for (int i = 0; i < facilities.size(); i++) {
    TextView titleText = new TextView(getContext());
    titleText.setText(facilities.get(i));
    titleText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(rightIc, 0, 0, 0);

    GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = 0;
    layoutParams.width = 0;
    int currentCol = i % 2;
    int currentRow = i / 2;
    // The last parameter in the specs is the weight, which gives equal size to the cells
    layoutParams.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(currentCol, 1, 1);
    layoutParams.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(currentRow, 1, 1);

    // Optional, if you want the text to be centered within the cell
    layoutParams.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    gridLayout.addView(titleText, layoutParams);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically that is the column and row count. I have re wrotten the complete logic

```
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(getContext());
    int total = facilities.size();
    int column =  2;
    int row = total / column;
    gridLayout.setAlignmentMode(GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS);
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(column);
    gridLayout.setRowCount(row + 1);
    TextView titleText;
    for(int i =0, c = 0, r = 0; i < total; i++, c++)
    { 
        if(c == column)
        { 
            c = 0;
            r++;
        } 
         titleText = new TextView(getContext());
         titleText.setText(facilities.get(i));
         gridLayout.addView(titleText, i);
         titleText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(rightIc, 0, 0, 0);
         GridLayout.LayoutParams param =new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
         param.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
         param.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
         param.rightMargin = 5;
         param.topMargin = 5;
         param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
         param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(c);
         param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(r);
         titleText.setLayoutParams (param);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's may be because of your dynamic text length is not fixed so each textview not take same space [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35693086/3514144)

```
int height=getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin); //set size of dimen in required resolution
```

titleText .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, height, height));

Comment: text can be at most 15 char max

Comment: You can set min width for textview,or fix the textview width is the easiest way if you have just 15char length in textview

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
GridLayout gl = findViewById( R.id.grid_layout );
TextView tv = new TextView( this );
tv.setText( ""+cursor.getInt( column ) ); //for example
GridLayout.LayoutParams lp = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
lp.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec( GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1, GridLayout.FILL ); //for stretch a child to column use GridLayout.FILL
gl.addView( tv, lp );
//DO NOT USE lp.setGravity( ... );
//FOR ALIGN TEXT USE tv.setTextAlignment( ... );
```