# dynamic EditText different size in different resolutions

Tags: java, android

```
 for(int l=0;l<c.getCount();l++)
 {
     EditText etpob = new EditText(this.getActivity());
     etpob.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
     int po=Integer.parseInt("1" + c.getInt(3)) ;
     etpob.setId(po);
     etpob.setHint("POB");
     etpob.setText("");
     etpob.setTextSize(15);
     etpob.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     etpob.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 50, 15));
     etpob.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
}
```

I have added the `EditText dynamically` above is my code, But it resolution fails out for different types of screen,in layout using styles we can change it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
etpob.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ConvertPixels(50), ConvertPixels(15))); 

public int  ConvertPixels(int ht)
    {
        int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,ht, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        return height;
    }
```

Used existing utility method built called TypedValue.applyDimensions(int, float, DisplayMetrics)

Answer (score 1):

You can use dimension for setting width of dynamic generated edittext

```
int pixels = 15; // use dimen here 
float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float dips = pixels / scale;
```

So,

```
 etpob.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, pixels , pixels ));
```

or if it is require you can set dimen and than you can do it like this way

getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin); //set size of dimen in required resolution

Comment: I have a doubt,why you given `float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float dips = pixels / scale;` because your not using anywhere

Comment: this is just an example for this my intention is just to use dimen in java file

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same way.

Define the parameters in style files and use it in code.

Check below link for reference

[How to retrieve style attributes programmatically from styles.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719103/how-to-retrieve-style-attributes-programatically-from-styles-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Incase the editText needs to `match_parent`

```
 Point size = new Point();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
 width = size.x;
```

And set width to EditText

```
 editText.setWidth(width);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use an static integer in your code for size of your EditText, must use values folder in different sizes.
create in res folder these folders: values-small, values-normal,values-large,values-xlarge.
in these folder make a resources file with Integer values. like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="edittext_width">70</integer>
    <integer name="edittext_height">30</integer>
</resources>
```

you can set this values with same name but different values in these folders.
then, you must use it in your code:

```
etpob.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,  getResources().getInteger(R.integer.edittext_width),  getResources().getInteger(R.integer.edittext_height)));
```

GOOD LUCK.